# Как использовать Rest API отдельно от сайта Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

Всем привет! Хотел создать сайт парсер объявлений и нужно написать к нему как сервис rest api, в который будет хранить, изменять, удалять и добавлять информацию об объявлениях. Будет ли уместно сделать это в одном проекте? Просто сделать роутинг api и web. Или создать отдельные два проекта, где будет сайт и rest, как bulletin и bulletin-service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отделять API от монолита стоит при одном из 3 условий:

1. Вы планируете, что над проектом будет работать несколько программистов, и каждый будет ответственен за свою часть. Так будет проще шарить и мержить проект кусками.
2. Вы планируете высоконагруженный проект с контейнеризацией в кубер кластер или бессерверную архитектуру.
3. Вы предполагаете, что логика парсера (сервиса) будет прожорливой и будет сжирать ресурсы, необходимые для сайта.

В ином случае, я думаю, что отделение избыточно и приведёт к потере скорости разработки.

Comment: Благодарю, доброго дня!